# Error in list of function arguments: '=' not recognized. Unable to parse query text

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2008, odbc

I am generating an error in visual studio 2008's query pane that I can't seem to figure out.

> Error in list of function arguments: '=' not recognized. Unable to parse query text.

After some cleaning up on the syntax and adding some proper quotations the issue still persisted. I attempted to execute the query anyway and it ends up waiting endlessly in visual studio 2008.

This is the query.

```sql
 SELECT 
 leg.tsrido, 
 leg.tsrnum, 
 shipment.dosvlg, 
 condition(leg.tsakti = 1, load.land, unload.land), 
 condition(leg.tsakti = 1, load.postun, unload.postun), 
 condition(leg.tsakti = 1, load.tsadr1, unload.tsadr1) 

 FROM 
 tsroma leg 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM tsdsmd WHERE (srtdos = 'd')) shipment 
 ON leg.dosvlg = shipment.dosvlg 

 LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM tsdnaw WHERE (tsroln = 1)) load 
 ON leg.dosvlg = load.dosvlg 

 LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM tsdnaw WHERE (tsroln = 3)) unload 
 ON leg.dosvlg = unload.dosvlg 

 WHERE (leg.tsrido = 79106279)

 ORDER BY 2
```

I am using ODBC and the connection string includes Driver={UNIMS}. It is a very old database that I have to support in my application.

There's probably a fault in the syntax somewhere, but I can't see it.

**Edit1:**
Here is an example condition code that "WORKS" on the UNIMS database. (Taken out of an AnsiString in the old application.)

```
condition(leg.tstohn = '" + pAuthorization[7] + "', shipment.pllaad, shipment.pllos)
condition(leg.tstohn = '" + pAuthorization[7] + "', shipment.tslzcd, shipment.tsuzcd)
condition(leg.tstohn = '" + pAuthorization[7] + "', shipment.lalaad, shipment.lalos)         
condition(leg.tstohn = '" + pAuthorization[7] + "', shipment.nmlaad, shipment.nmlos) zkafz
condition(leg.tstohn = '" + pAuthorization[7] + "', shipment.adrlaa, shipment.adrlos)
```

**Edit2:**

Also unable to find much documentation on UNIMS SQL UNIMS SQL. Here's more information that might help.

- Driver={UNIMS};
- .NET Framework Data Provider for ODBC
- UNIMS SQL
- State Open
- Version 02.05.0028

**Edit3:**
Here is the entire C# Code

```cs
public string qShipments(string a)
{
    string q = "";
    #region Oracle
    if (env == "Oracle")
    {
        /* string Oracle_Shipment
         * Alias issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14218695/ora-00972-identifier-is-too-long
                        SELECT DISTINCT
                        csl."tripNumber",
                        csl."shipmentNumber",
                        csl."legType",
                        csl."planSequence",
                        csl."toHubSearchname",
                        CASE WHEN csl."legType" = 1 THEN Address1."countryCode" ELSE Address3."countryCode" END countryCode,
                        CASE WHEN csl."legType" = 1 THEN Address1."postcode" ELSE Address3."postcode" END postcode,
                        CASE WHEN csl."legType" = 1 THEN Address1."streetLine1" ELSE  Address3."streetLine1" END streetLine

                        FROM 
                        "cef_v_cw_trip" ct 
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN "cef_v_cw_shipmentLegs" csl 
                        ON ct."tripNumber" = csl."tripNumber"

                        LEFT OUTER JOIN "cef_v_cw_shipment" cs 
                        ON csl."shipmentNumber" = cs."shipmentNumber"

                        LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM "cef_v_cw_fileAddress" WHERE "addressRole" = 1) Address1
                        ON cs."shipmentNumber" = Address1."fileNumber"

                        LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM "cef_v_cw_fileAddress" WHERE "addressRole" = 3) Address3
                        ON cs."shipmentNumber" = Address3."fileNumber"

                        WHERE ct."tripNumber" = '1045013'
                        AND csl."toHubSearchname" <> ' '
                        ORDER BY 4
         */
        q = string.Format("SELECT DISTINCT " +
                             "csl.\"tripNumber\", " +
                             "csl.\"shipmentNumber\", " +
                             "csl.\"legType\", " +
                             "csl.\"planSequence\", " +
                             "csl.\"toHubSearchname\", " +
                             "CASE WHEN csl.\"legType\" = 1 THEN Address1.\"countryCode\" ELSE Address3.\"countryCode\" END countryCode, " +
                             "CASE WHEN csl.\"legType\" = 1 THEN Address1.\"postcode\" ELSE Address3.\"postcode\" END postcode, " +
                             "CASE WHEN csl.\"legType\" = 1 THEN Address1.\"streetLine1\" ELSE  Address3.\"streetLine1\" END streetLine " +
                             "FROM " +
                             "\"{0}v_cw_trip\" ct " +
                             "LEFT OUTER JOIN \"{0}v_cw_shipmentLegs\" csl " +
                             "ON ct.\"tripNumber\" = csl.\"tripNumber\" " +
                             "LEFT OUTER JOIN \"{0}v_cw_shipment\" cs " +
                             "ON csl.\"shipmentNumber\" = cs.\"shipmentNumber\" " +
                             "LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM \"{0}v_cw_fileAddress\" WHERE \"addressRole\" = 1) Address1 " +
                             "ON cs.\"shipmentNumber\" = Address1.\"fileNumber\" " +
                             "LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM \"{0}v_cw_fileAddress\" WHERE \"addressRole\" = 3) Address3 " +
                             "ON cs.\"shipmentNumber\" = Address3.\"fileNumber\" " +
                             "WHERE ct.\"tripNumber\" = {1} " +
                             "AND csl.\"toHubSearchname\" <> ' ' " +
                             "ORDER BY 4", prefix, a.ToString());
    }
    #endregion

    #region UNIMS
    if (env == "UNIMS")
    {
        /* string Unims shipment  
         * http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14379573/error-in-list-of-function-arguments-not-recognized-unable-to-parse-query-t
             SELECT 
             leg.tsrido, 
             leg.tsrnum, 
             shipment.dosvlg, 
             condition(leg.tsakti = 1, load.land, unload.land), 
             condition(leg.tsakti = 1, load.postun, unload.postun), 
             condition(leg.tsakti = 1, load.tsadr1, unload.tsadr1) 

             FROM 
             tsroma leg 
             LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM tsdsmd WHERE (srtdos = 'd')) shipment 
             ON leg.dosvlg = shipment.dosvlg 

             LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM tsdnaw WHERE (tsroln = 1)) load 
             ON leg.dosvlg = load.dosvlg 

             LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM tsdnaw WHERE (tsroln = 3)) unload 
             ON leg.dosvlg = unload.dosvlg 

             WHERE (leg.tsrido = 79106279)

             ORDER BY 2
         */
        q = string.Format("SELECT " +
                        "leg.tsrido, " +
                        "leg.tsrnum, " +
                        "shipment.dosvlg, " +
                        "condition(leg.tsakti = 1, load.land, unload.land), " +
                        "condition(leg.tsakti = 1, load.postun, unload.postun), " +
                        "condition(leg.tsakti = 1, load.tsadr1, unload.tsadr1) " +
                        "FROM " +
                        "tsroma leg " +
                        "LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM tsdsmd WHERE srtdos = 'd') shipment " +
                        "ON leg.dosvlg = shipment.dosvlg " +
                        "LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM tsdnaw where tsroln = 1) load " +
                        "ON leg.dosvlg = load.dosvlg " +
                        "LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM tsdnaw where tsroln = 3) unload " +
                        "ON leg.dosvlg = unload.dosvlg " +
                        "WHERE leg.tsrido = {1} " +
                        "ORDER BY 2", prefix, a.ToString());
    }
    #endregion
    return q;
}
```

**Edit4:**
I noticed that the query is endless when I remove the cases below. I think I am going to reconsider my ODBC connection first.

**Edit5:**
Does not seem to work in PuTTY or directly to the machine either in most cases. It just ends up in a resource hogging query for some reason. New approach: problem resolved with the right query in PuTTY but this is not yet accepted in ODBC Unims

```
                select 
                    leg.tsrido, 
                    leg.tsrnum, 
                    dosier.dosvlg, 
                    condition(leg.tsakti = 1, dosier.lalaad, dosier.lalos), 
                    condition(leg.tsakti = 1, dosier.pklaad, dosier.pklos), 
                    condition(leg.tsakti = 1, dosier.tsla1,  dosier.tsua1) 

                from 
                    tsroma leg 
                    left outer join dosier 
                    on leg.dosvlg = dosier.dosvlg 
                where 
                    leg.tsrido = 79106279

                order by 2;
```

**Final Edit:**

Above code works properly despite that visual studio does not recognize the unims syntax for the conditions. Old queries were stuck and over 100 MB in size according to the server, killed those processes. 10 year old databases are a strange thing indeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not familiar with UniMS, but perhaps one of the following would work:

```
             (case when leg.tsakti = 1 then load.land else unload.land end), 
             (case when condition(leg.tsakti = 1 then load.postun else unload.postun end), 
             (case when condition(leg.tsakti = 1 then load.tsadr1 else unload.tsadr1 end)
```

or:

```
             iif(leg.tsakti = 1, load.land, unload.land), 
             iif(leg.tsakti = 1, load.postun, unload.postun), 
             iif(leg.tsakti = 1, load.tsadr1, unload.tsadr1)
```

or:

```
             if(leg.tsakti = 1, load.land, unload.land), 
             if(leg.tsakti = 1, load.postun, unload.postun), 
             if(leg.tsakti = 1, load.tsadr1, unload.tsadr1)
```

These work in some other databases.

Comment: these all return Error in list of function arguments: '=' not recognized.
Unable to parse query text. but thank you for these suggestions. I will show the entire code.

Comment: I have, even used all quotes for the values. Unfortunately there's just a nameless encrypted .dll shipped with the old application made by the previous programmer. I think this may be a driver and server version mismatch or something similiar.

Comment: This has come the closet to what my solution was. I will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use when state instead of iif. This way I solved the problem.

```
(case when ISNULL(pp.ProductPrice,0) > 0 then ISNULL(pd.AmountDiscount,0)  else 0 end) AmountDiscount
```

We can write this code using SQL IIF statement syntax as following.

```
IIF(boolean_expression, true_value, false_value)
```

Also here is a nice article, maybe it will be useful . After IIF 2012, sql server emerged as a conditioning method, there are still some errors, I guess. For example, its use with ISNULL is not very stable, but instead it makes more sense to use "case when".

https://www.sqlshack.com/overview-of-sql-iif-statement/